# Sentry Docker Error opening GeoIP database

Tags: geo, sentry

I added GeoLite2-Country.mmdb and GeoIP.dat to sentry project root, but it keep showing this error message

```
08:41:04 [WARNING] sentry.utils.geo: Error opening GeoIP database: ../GeoLite2-Country.mmdb
08:41:04 [WARNING] sentry.utils.geo: Error opening GeoIP database in Rust: ../GeoLite2-Country.mmdb
```

I also added mmdb path to sentry.conf.py

```
GEOIP_PATH_MMDB = '../GeoLite2-Country.mmdb'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to place it in `/etc/sentry/` folder and edit `GEOIP_PATH_MMDB = '/etc/sentry/GeoLite2-Country.mmdb'`.

This hack is helped me.